# I have a Brother DCP-J315 Printer which Ubuntu sees but will not print from wirelessly

Tags: networking

I have tried to set it up but am new to Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download the **cups** driver.](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/dcpj315wcupswrapper-1.1.3-1.i386.deb&lang=English_gpl) Press accept to download.
2. [Download the **LPR** driver.](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/dcpj315wlpr-1.1.3-1.i386.deb&lang=English_lpr) Press accept to download.

The downloaded file is `.deb` extension then open terminal and do this:

```
cd ~/Download
sudo dpkg -i ####.deb
```

Replace `###` by the name of file downloaded.

Check these pages for more information:

- [**LPR Driver Installer** | brother.com (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140319074536/http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html)
- [**Cupswrapper Driver Install** | brother.com (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109175208/http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html)